# Choosing a suitable FET for a design project

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, bjt, jfet

I'm currently working on a project to produce a  high speed and high voltage pulse. I'm trying to find a suitable FET.
I intended to supply a voltage of about 50v to circuit. And using the FET to go on and off behaving somewhat like a switch, thus somewhat creating a fast pulse.

However the requirement to produce I require a FET, that will allow to have a switching time in the region of 1ns and also needs a voltage threshold about 50v.

MOSFETs are suitable for this case as I remember reading the voltage threshold and switching times  directly related. A fast switching MOSFET has low voltage threshold. visa versa.
When looking at power MOSFETS, they also don't seem to suitable.
BJTs however I cant seem to find out with a high enough voltage threshold.

Sic JFET (silicone Carbide) - The rise time is too slow in order for them to be suitable choice.

If anyone has got any suggestions for a suitable FET , that has both a fast switching time (in the region of 1ns) and has a high voltage threshold (approximately 50v), please let me know.

Comment: What is the output load you are driving?

Comment: I require a minimum 30v to drive the component. If that's what you mean ?

Comment: No, what is the output load you are driving - the component you refer to.

Comment: i'm going to be driving a single OLED cell. If i can get one.

Comment: Well, you can't design the driver without knowledge of the load.

Comment: Are you trying to design an high speed pulser for driving LASER/LED diodes in a very fast way? If so, your choice is not restricted to MOSFETs/JFETs: you can also consider avalanche transistor circuits, which can suit your need of high speed and high power/voltage driving.